# How to run an executable jar from within Spring container?

Tags: java, spring

I need to run an executable jar from within my Spring app asynchronously, and I was wondering if Spring had any quick, convenient way to do this without anything complicated like Spring Batch?

At this point I would have to create a Thread to accomplish the asych part, and then run my jar via this old code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar etc...");
```

I tried researching this but the results are all about creating a Spring Boot executable jar, I'm not finding a good search term to filter all that noise out. I also found some task scheduling stuff which looks pretty complicated.

I don't need any fancy features - just literally run that jar and continue processing! No scheduling.

Comment: If you say that you don't need any fancy features, why are you looking to do this using some Spring feature, (which could be considered fancy depending on one's point of view) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to stick with the way that you are currently doing it.  If you run the executable JAR in the same JVM as the Spring container, then there is a risk that the JAR will do things that interfere with container itself; e.g. leak memory, start threads and not clean up, call `System.exit`, change the `System.in/out/err` streams, etcetera.